# ¿Cómo obtener el número de elementos en un observable de Firestore?

Tags: angular, typescript

Necesito obtener el número de elementos que tengo en un observable que obtiene datos de firestore.

Aquí declaro mis variables:

```
private imagenCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Imagen>;
imagenes: Observable<Imagen[]>;
```

Aquí inicializo mis variables en el constructor:

```
this.imagenCollection = afs.collection<Imagen>('img-destacada-blog');
this.imagenes = this.imagenCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
  return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Imagen;
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return { id, ...data };
  });
});
```

Y utilizando una función necesito obtener el número de elementos que se encuentran en el observable ìmagenes`:

```
subirImagenDestacada() {
  let n = this.imagenes.length;
  alert(n);
}
```

Pero aquí me tira el error en `Property length does not exist on type Observable<Imagen[]>`

¿Hay una manera de obtener el valor del número de elementos que tiene almacenados?

Answer (score 1):

Una observable no contiene la propiedad length, primero, es necesario suscribirse. Dentro de la suscripción puedes ya manipular la lista.

```
subirImagenDestacada() {
  this.imagenes.subscribe(
  // Aquí el valor de value contiene el arreglo
  value => alert(value.length),

  // Se ejecuta cuando hubo un error
  error => alert(error),

  // Opcional, se ejecuta cuando termina el proceso asíncrono
  () => alert("finished")
}
```

Una observable no se ejecuta hasta que alguien se suscribe a ella.